# PHP system() mysqldump makes my page not responding

Tags: php, system, mysql

With **PHP** on my `WIN 7` + `localhost`, i'm testing to dump a mysql database via:
`system(mysqldump <parameters>)`. But **while i run the code, my page is gone hanged (not responding)** by never ending with loading sign. The test database is quite tiny. Whats wrong with it?

Here are the steps i've done for this work:

- `system ('mysqldump -u rootname -p rootpw dbname > output.sql');`
- Add the full path of `mysqldump.exe` into `Windows Environment Variables`

When i run the code, there appear `output.sql` file with just `0 kb` sized and the page is not responding.

Comment: try removing the space between `-p` and `rootpw`, same for `-u`

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the time limit:

```
// If system call
set_time_limit(600); 

// Otherwise
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
```

- [set_time_limit reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)
- [max_execution_time reference](http://us.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Also, if you want to see what your database is doing, do a `show full processlist` from the mysql command line.